# LINQ to NHibernate can't get to children's children

Tags: linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mappings

I have entity A which has an IList of B called Bs and B has an IList of C called Cs.

I want to search for all A's which have at least 5 C's in them. So I went and wrote

```
using (var s = this._sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    IQueryable<A> q = s.Linq<A>();
    // some code...
    if (range.Min.HasValue)                    
        q = q.Where(a => a.Bs.Sum(b => b.Cs.Count) >= range.Min.Value);
    // some code...
    return q.Select(b=>b).ToArray();
 }
```

However upon executing the code (and having Min specified in the range variable) I get the following exception :

NHibernate.QueryException : could not resolve property: Cs of: A

Why does it look for the B's property on A? The mappings seem to be right though :

The (Fluent) mapping on A says :

```
//...
HasMany(a => a.Bs)
 .Table("Bs")
 .KeyColumn("IdA")
 .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
 .Inverse()
 .Not.LazyLoad();
//...
```

and on the mapping on B says :

```
//...
HasMany(b => b.Cs)
 .Table("Cs")
 .KeyColumn("IdB")
 .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
 .Inverse()
 .Not.LazyLoad();
References(b => b.A, "IdA")
 .Not.LazyLoad();
//...
```

finally on the mapping on C :

```
References(c => c.B, "IdB").Not.LazyLoad();
```

Comment: You may want to try the newer Linq provider in the NHibernate trunk.  The NHContrib Linq provider has more limited functionality.

Comment: I have the latest LINQ provider from the NHibernate trunk and it doesn't fix my problem :(((((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with LINQ to NHibernate 2.x

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to NHibernate is great for making simple queries easy to do. However, when you need to do complex queries (such as this one) it is often better to switch to the criteria API or HQL. You have 3 querying methods at your disposal, use them all.

That being said once NHibernate 3.0 is released it may be possible to do this query using LINQ.

Comment: So I understand that this is not yet possible with the latest released LINQ provider for NHibernate..